# Xcode wont let me use setRootViewController

Tags: xcode

The error to be exact is this:

Thread 1: Exception: "-[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000240c0f0"

The line causing it is this one:

[self.window setRootViewController: taarVC];

taarVC is a UITabBarController already defined with its own array, I am new and I am trying to learn code, but cannot seem to find answers

the rest of the code is this: (I still need to put the images)

```
ListCitiesViewController *vc1 =[[ListCitiesViewController alloc] init];
vc1.title = @"List";
vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""] ;

MapCitiesViewController *vc2 = [[MapCitiesViewController alloc] init];
vc2.title = @"Map";
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""] ;

ProfileViewController *vc3 = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
vc3.title = @"Profile";
vc3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

UINavigationController *nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
UINavigationController *nc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
UINavigationController *nc3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];

NSArray *arrayNC = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: nc1, nc2, nc3, nil];

UITabBarController *taarVC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[taarVC setViewControllers:arrayNC];
```

[self.window setRootViewController: taarVC];

Comment: Are you using the new `SceneDelegate`? If so, `AppDelegate` no longer has a `window` property by default.

Comment: Thanks fot the fast reply! I do not know what the SceneDelegate, I just know that its the latest Xcode, so I assume it is. And if AppDelegate no longer has a window property how can I give it to it?